# How to mock any_instance in a scope with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking, bdd

I'm trying to write a spec which expects a method to be called on all instances in a scope. Couldn't find a elegant way to do it.

This is a simplified representation of my code:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base

scope :active, where(:status => 'active')
scope :inactive, where(:status => 'inactive')

def some_action
  # some code
end
```

This class is used by another class which calls `some_action` on `MyClass.all`:

```
class OtherClass

def other_method
  MyClass.all.each do |item|
    item.some_action
  end
end
```

I want to change it to:

```
class OtherClass

def other_method
  MyClass.active.each do |item|
    item.some_action
  end
end
```

To test such behavior I could simply `MyClass.stub(:active)`, return an Array of stubs and expect `some_action` on each stub. But I don't like that approach because it exposes too much details of the implementation.

What I thing would be a little more elegant is something like `any_instance_in_scope`. Then I could simply write my spec as:

```
MyClass.any_instance_in_scope(:active).should_receive(:some_action)
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `MyClass.all.some_action` isn't going to work since `MyClass#some_action` is an instance method, meanwhile `MyClass#all` returns an `Array` -- so when you do `MyClass.all.some_action` you're actually calling `Array#some_action`.

Also, note `MyClass.all` and `MyClass.active` return different classes:

```
MyClass.active.class # => ActiveRecord::Relation
MyClass.active.all.class # => Array
```

I am not sure what your `some_action` should do... Some options I imagine you might want to do:

## Option #1: Narrowing of a database query

If `some_action` is filtering the array, you should convert it to be yet another scope, doing something like this:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, where(:status => 'active')
  scope :inactive, where(:status => 'inactive')
  scope :some_action, ->(color_name) { where(color: color_name) }
end
```

And then call it using `MyClass.active.some_action('red').all`. If you only want the first result, `MyClass.active.some_action('red').first`.

### How to test `scope` with RSpec

This is a good answer to it (and the reasons why): [Testing named scopes with RSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485379/testing-named-scopes-with-rspec).

## Option #2: Executing an action on top of an instance

Let's say you really want to have `MyClass#some_action` defined as an instance method. Then, you can try doing this:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, where(status: 'active')
  scope :inactive, where(status: 'inactive')

  def some_action
    self.foo = 'bar'
    self
  end
end
```

In this case, you may execute it with `MyClass.active.last.some_action`, simply because `#last` will return an instance, not the entire array.

### How to test `some_action` with RSpec

I believe you should simply test it with expectations:

```
MyClass.should_receive(:some_action).at_least(:once)
MyClass.active.last.some_action
```

Additional discussion on this: [How to say any_instance should_receive any number of times in RSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800992/how-to-say-any-instance-should-receive-any-number-of-times-in-rspec)

### Option #3: Mass action

Let's say you really want to run `MyClass.active.some_action`. I'd recommend you first try this (same example as Option #2):

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, where(status: 'active')
  scope :inactive, where(status: 'inactive')

  def some_action
    self.foo = 'bar'
    self
  end
end
```

And then run with `MyClass.active.all.map{|my_class| my_class.some_action }`.

Now, if you *really* want to implement `MyClass.active.some_action` -- you want `some_action` to be executed over all instances of ActiveRecord::Relation (**which I don't recommend**), do this:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, where(status: 'active')
  scope :inactive, where(status: 'inactive')

  def some_action
    # really do it
  end
end
```

And...

```
class ActiveRecord::Relation
  # run some_action over all instances
  def some_action
    to_a.each {|object| object.some_action }.tap { reset }
  end
end
```

Again, I **don't recommend doing this**.

### How to test `some_action` with RSpec

Same case as Option #2:

```
MyClass.should_receive(:some_action).at_least(:once)
MyClass.active.last.some_action
```

---

*Note: All codes are using Ruby 2.0.0-p0. Install and use it, it's fun! :-)*

Comment: sorry, there was a huge mistake in OtherClass. Changed my question to reflect te original intention better.